# php form passing value into php shell_exec

Tags: php, youtube-dl

I am trying to create a simple page that downloads youtube videos with the help of youtube-dl app.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="youtubedl" value="dload YouTube">
<input type="text" name="addr" value="">
</form>
```

PHP part looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$link = escapeshellarg($_GET["addr"]);
if(isset($_POST['youtubedl']))
 {
   $output=shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl $link");
   echo $link;
   echo $output;
 }
?>
```

I think my variable is not getting passed onto PHP as echo $link is not producing any output.

error.log returns `ERROR: u'' is not a valid URL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `addr` in `$_GET` while it will be in `$_POST` since you use `method="post"`.

Answer (score 1):

What @Jonas Äppelgran said, and I would add this,

I would do a better check on the link, so instead of testing it this way:

```
$link = escapeshellarg($_GET["addr"]);
if(isset($_POST['youtubedl']))
{
 ...
```

I would check it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['youtubedl']) && !empty($_POST['addr'])){
     $link = escapeshellarg($_POST["addr"]);
     ...
```

The way you currently have it you could get an Undefined Index `addr` when the page is loaded outside of posting the form.  Because, you are evaluating it before the condition.  And even if you simply moved it to inside the if, what's to stop the form from submitting an empty address.